# Inflate action mode menu based on the item that was clicked

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I have an activity that on a tablet uses the master/detail flow for a checkbook app (accounts on the left, transactions on the right).

When an item is hard pressed I use a contextual action bar to allow the user to edit/delete the items if necessary. I do so like this:

```
@Override
public void onTransactionLongClick(Transaction t) {
    if(mActionMode == null){
        // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback already defined
        mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        // Get name to set as title for action bar
        mActionMode.setTitle(t.getDescription());
        // Get account ID to pass as tag.
        mActionMode.setTag(t);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccountLongSelected(AccountPrimitives ap) {
    // Don't fire if the action mode is already active.
    if(mActionMode == null){
        // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback already defined
        mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        // Get name to set as title for action bar
        mActionMode.setTitle(ap.getName());
        // Get account ID to pass as tag.
        mActionMode.setTag(ap);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I get the item that was selected and I pass that as the tag to the action mode so I know which item to start editing or delete from the database if necessary.

Now that I have a two pane layout, I cannot setup my action mode callback properly. I want to do something like this:

```
private final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            // Inflate based on tag type (account/transaction)
            if(mActionMode.getTag() instanceof AccountPrimitives){
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.account_context_menu, menu);
            } else if(mActionMode.getTag() instanceof Transaction){
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.transaction_context_menu, menu);
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_delete_account:
                    // The account that was selected is passed as the tag
                    // for the action mode.
                    showAccountDeleteAlertDialog((AccountPrimitives) mActionMode.getTag());
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_delete_transaction:
                    showTransactionDeleteAlertDialog((Transaction) mActionMode.getTag());
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };
```

However, I get a null pointer exception because the action mode is started before I call mActionMode.setTag(), so I can't determine its type. In the `onXLongClick` methods I can't move the setTag() to the first line, because I also get an NPE.

How can I set a condition to inflate a specific menu for the action mode?

**EDIT**

When I long press an item, I get the following exception:

```
04-24 17:45:22.441    8117-8117/com.example.android.cashcaretaker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.cashcaretaker, PID: 8117
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.getTag()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.android.cashcaretaker.AccountsActivity$1.onCreateActionMode(AccountsActivity.java:58)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1451)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.dispatchOnCreate(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1015)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.startActionMode(WindowDecorActionBar.java:510)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:570)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivity.java:225)
            at com.example.android.cashcaretaker.AccountsActivity.onTransactionLongClick(AccountsActivity.java:177)
            at com.example.android.cashcaretaker.TransactionFragment$1.onItemLongClick(TransactionFragment.java:72)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3121)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3070)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I get the same exception for both accounts and transaction, the only difference is the method that calls them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was by creating a second `ActionMode.Callback` object. The first one I made to handle accounts, and the second to handle transactions.

They each look like the one above, and I was able to call them like this:

```
// In Account long click
mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mAccountActionModeCallback);

// In transaction long click
mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mTransactionActionModeCallback);
```

Then, in each of the callbacks I was able to inflate the necessary menu and handle the necessary action items.